# Add view to stack view and change height constraint to maintain ratio

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

When adding a new view to a stack view, I want to maintain the ratio of views inside the the stackview by increasing the stackview height constraint by the amount of the added view. I've been reading up on how to update view constraints but cant seem to make it work.

```
self.stackView?.insertArrangedSubview(self.userErrorLabel, at: 2)
self.heightConstraint = self.stackView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140 + self.stackView?.bounds.height)
self.stackView?.addConstraints([self.heightConstraint!])
self.stackView?.setNeedsLayout()
```

**Any advice would be extremely helpful!!**

Comment: You can do with storyboard as well

Comment: Whenever you give add any constraint, first you need to invalid all previous constraints and them active new constraints else conflicts may happened. take [ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html)

Comment: You should not add a new constraint to stackView for each time you add a subview. Just update the height of the stackview.

Comment: yes but how do you update the heightview constraint that is on the view is my question? I took a reference to it because I felt like that is the easiest way and i couldnt find it in view.constraints

Comment: the trick is to first remove the constraint and then add a new one. Thanks @ridvankucuk

Answer (score 0):

Are you using XIB or story board? you can register the height constraint as Outlet to your View/VC and then you can edit / increase the height there.
let say that you register the height constraint as

```
@IBOutlet weak var stackViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

all you need to do is just

```
let currentStackHeight = stackViewHeight.constant
stackViewHeight.constant = currentStackHeight + self.addedView.bounds.height
```

and just like that, you don't need to add or remove any constraint